# Response in variable is not displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, weather-api

[image][image][image]

> API response saved in clima variable showing undefined, but when i used console log it shows in response.data but not in clima i need some json formatting? Using wheaterStack API

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


const  Clima=(ciudad)=>{
    const [clima,setClima]=useState([])
    
    const api_key  =  process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY



    useEffect(()=>{
        //if(ciudad === undefined)
       // return
       // console.log(ciudad,'ciudadddddddds')
        axios
          .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${ciudad.city}`)
          .then(response =>{
            setClima(response.data)
            console.log(response.data)
            console.log(clima)
          }
    
          )
    
      },[api_key,ciudad])

    return(
      <div></div>
    )
}

export default Clima
```

Comment: What does setClima do and where is the code held?

Comment: this is a component and i pass the city and the api reposnse is some weather info of it , the code is local, but i try it on codesandbox and instead give 2 errors . https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-dream-ssqfv?file=/src/Clima.js

Comment: I am probably not going to be of great help, but could you describe the difference between Clima and clima?

Comment: Clima(weather is the translation) is the component wich i want to return with the info, clima is the variable wich i want to held the api response in the api response, i set the state in the api response.data to clima with setClima, when i inspect, in the image above, the state is correct, but when i console log clima, i get undefined, and response.data when console.log it i can see the api response correct in the console

Comment: Thanks - I should have been able to work that out. I have looked at the console log in the sandbox and you are getting an error which may be relevant. It's too long to post in a comment so I'll put it in an answer so you can see it

Comment: I used the https earlier when trying in my local enviroment but i get this message as i used the free subscription "105 https_access_restricted The user's current subscription plan does not support HTTPS." thnaks anyway for review the errors

Comment: Yes, I have now signed up to experiment. and have my own key Also I have updated the 'answer' as the http/https problem means that the sandbox cant be used to debug this problem I think. I cannot find the documentation for setCllima - can you point me to the right place (or documentation for setWeather I suppose?)

Comment: those are variables for using the hook useState of react https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Ah again. I am slowly catching up, thank you for explaining and also for introducing me to Weatherstack. The answer from @shamsup looks promising - it had to be something like a timing problem. Does it solve things for you?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the sandbox provided in the question I see this error:

```
xhr.js:184 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codesandbox.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=undefined&query=New+York'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:184
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:76
wrap @ bind.js:9
eval @ App.js? [sm]:14
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:19731
commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:19769
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:292
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:22853
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11039
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:22820
eval @ react-dom.development.js:22699
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:164
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:91)
```

It looks as though the get: you have set up needs to be an https not an http request. As there is no checking on the response, just a call to setClima could this be the problem? ie that setClima is not loaded or in some way cannot cope with what you are giving it?

I don't really believe this can be the answer since you are in a sense checking on response and it seems to contain data that you reckon is OK, so something has worked fine. However, it might be worth setting that get: to https rather than http to see if anything changes.

(this answer is more of a continuation of discussion in comments but the error was too big to put in a comment hence I've created this 'answer').

EDIT: it is I believe a problem with using sandbox - it is called with https so a get: http is rejected. It is not the problem in real life, but it does mean the sandbox can't be used to help debuggin.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the value of `clima` is never being set, but really the console log is just never happening with the updated data. `setClima` doesn't change the variable value immediately, and will instead trigger an update that tells React it needs to rerender the component.

```
    axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${ciudad.city}`)
      .then(response =>{
        setClima(response.data) // set state and queues update
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(clima) // logs what clima is on this render
      })
```

In order to read the value of clima, the console log should be placed outside of the `useEffect` call.

```js
const [clima, setClima] = useState([]);

console.log(clima); // will be [] on first call, and the response data on second call

useEffect(()=>{
        axios
          .get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${api_key}&query=${ciudad.city}`)
          .then(response =>{
            setClima(response.data)
          })
  },[api_key,ciudad])
```

The log will happen twice, once with the initial state value (`[]`) and once with the response data when the component updates.

Comment: i post a image above, it takes the value later, the first times it gets undefined